# How to stick an image to cursor by clicking on the image in flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, image, flex4, cursor

I'm having a panel which shows an image and control bar with buttons in the form of thumbnail image of right mark. When a user clicks on the thumbnail of right mark I want to stick the thumbnail image of that right mark to the mouse pointer and when he clicks on the image, the thumbnail related image should be paste on the image. Same concept of drag and drop with click event.

Comment: Can you post some code to show the setup of your app?  What you're asking is fairly simple, just it would help to know a bit more.

Comment: Hi @shanethehat, I've edited the post with details. Please check it once.

Comment: This question is really hard to follow!

Comment: Hi @shanethehat- If possible let me know how to stick a thumbnail image(whose buttonmode is true) to mouse pointer when the thumbnail image is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is still pretty hard to understand, but I'm fairly certain that what you need is [Sprite#startDrag()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#startDrag%28%29) and [Sprite#stopDrag()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#stopDrag%28%29).

Here's a little example setup to get you started:

```
<s:layout>
    <s:HorizontalLayout/>
</s:layout>

<s:Button label="pick it up" click="myImage.startDrag(true)" />
<s:Image id="myImage" source="@Embed('test.png')" />
<s:Button label="drop it" click="myImage.stopDrag()" />
```

Note that I set the `lockCenter` argument to true. This will make the Image stick to the mouse. Otherwise you would start dragging the image from its original location.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:to pick button single click and to drop you have to do double click.

```
<mx:LinkButton id="myLButton" height="100" width="100" color="red" label="Click"
          doubleClickEnabled="true" click="myLButton.startDrag(false)" doubleClick="myLButton.stopDrag()"/>
```